# if current_user_can() function 500 error

Tags: php, wordpress

I' trying to write a function that will hide the admin bar for certain users. I'm borrowing some code from the hide admin bar plugin. I've written the following which results in a server error:

```
<?php
/*Hides the Admin Bar in WordPress 3.1+
Tweaked Hide Admin Bar plugin */

if (  current_user_can('moderate_comments')  ) {
    function hide_admin_bar_prefs() {
        ?>

        <style type="text/css">
            .show-admin-bar {display: none;}
        </style> 

    <?php 
    }

    add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'hide_admin_bar_prefs' );
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_false' );
}

?>
```

If I change the if statement to a true or false equation, it works properly. For instance if I use

```
if (1 == 1) {... 
or 
if (1 == 2) {...
```

it works as I would expect. What am I missing?

Comment: Please read the PHP Frequently Asked Questions here: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/php/info and learn how to enable error reporting.

Comment: add_action and add_filter are not generic php functions. You could get a better response if you explained the framework/environment.

Comment: @automaticoo wordpress? it's even tagged. add_action() and add_filter() are maybe the most used wp functions

Comment: Your code seems to run fine on my own local sandbox environment. If you can enable error reporting (as Mathieu recommends) it should pinpoint the specific issue you're having.

Comment: Yep, it's tagged wordpress. The php tag was applied automatically because of my code. They are standard built in wp functions. current_user_can() is also a built in wp function.

Comment: An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.

Comment: @DamienPirsy Sorry didn't notice it at first. I never worked with wordpress before.

Comment: Next to PHP error reporting setting to highest level and the enabling of error logging in PHP, enable WP_DEBUG: http://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG

Comment: Ok, that actually helped. Nice trick to know. Here's what I'm getting : Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_get_current_user() in /var/www/html/wp-includes/capabilities.php on line 1281

Comment: Here's the code from the error  `* @param string $capability Capability or role name.
 * @return bool
 */
function current_user_can( $capability ) {
 $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

 if ( empty( $current_user ) )
  return false;

 $args = array_slice( func_get_args(), 1 );
 $args = array_merge( array( $capability ), $args );

 return call_user_func_array( array( $current_user, 'has_cap' ), $args );
}`

Comment: Where is this code? How are you loading it?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're copy-and-pasting from another plugin, could it be possible that you're re-declaring the `hide_admin_bar_prefs()` function here? Check if disabling the plugin that you're copying this code from will resolve this issue. If that's the case then using a different function name will most likely fix your problem (and make sure to change the second parameter in your call to `add_action()` accordingly).